# How to apply Twitter bt-lg css class to file browse input button

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to style a file input button to look like the add file button here:

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html

I tried to add the twitter bootstrap btn-success bt-lg css and set the input file button opacity:0

I am having a hard time getting the input button the exact size as the input button on the blueimp website:

The button is just too large and I cannot adjust the height/width.

I applied the twitter btn-lg css and thought that would take care of the sizing.

All other buttons can size as btn-lg css escept for the input button.

My css is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" id="theme">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Scripts/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<style>
    #fileadd{
    opacity:0;
    }
```

I tried adding the css of the Twitter bt-lg class directly on the page

```
    #btnfile {
padding: 10px 16px;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 1.33;
border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Here is the input button:

```
<div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
                    <label id="btnfile"class="btn btn-success btn-lg fileinput-button">
                        <span>Add files...</span>
                        <input id="fileadd" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                    </label>
@*                    <span id="uploadbtn" class="btn btn-success">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                </span>*@
                    <button class="btn-primary btn-lg"  type="submit">Start upload</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn-warning btn-lg">Cancel upload</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-danger btn-lg">Delete files</button>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just change the opacity of the file input, it will still take up all the default space, I would just copy the styles from the blueimp plugin:

```
#btnfile {
    position: relative;
}
#fileadd {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    transform: translate(-300px, 0) scale(4);
    font-size: 23px;
    direction: ltr;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/vY4fm/)**